# Debug a Webworker

Tags: javascript, debugging, html

What's the best way to debug a webworker? My worker appears to be failing somewhere, but I don't appear to be able to log things to the console to figure out what's going on. Is there a way using firebug, or webkit's inspector I can run javascript in the webworker context? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The Webkit nightlies have web worker debugging facilities if I recall correctly.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to debug web workers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323778/how-to-debug-web-workers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment no browser supports debugging of web workers. I've tested

- Chrome 7.0.517.24 dev
- Firefox 3.6.10
- WebKit nightly r68636

There is a nice [article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/25/web-workers-errors-and-debugging/) by Nicholas Zakas about debugging web workers.

Comment: This is essentially what I already had. Chrome has a pseudo-debugger for webworkers, but it basically just puts them in an iframe and connects the onmessage/postMessage handlers properly.

Answer (score 4):

Debugging workers is now available in chrome.

look out the [article of chromium blog]

http://blog.chromium.org/2012/04/debugging-web-workers-with-chrome.html