# Debug cache-busted scripts in production

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a front-end project (JavaScript files) and the server adds a cache-busting value to the end of the URL, e.g., `http://www.example.com/myfile.js&bust=0.5647534393`

My problem is I lose any breakpoints set in Chrome's Developer Tools after reloading. **I do not have access to the server to disable it.**

Is there any way to work around this constraint?

UPDATE: Adding `debugger;` to the JS source code is not a viable solution because I'm debugging production code.

Comment: i can't recall ever seeing anything like this, seems like a good point to bring up...

Comment: have you tried location.reload(true) in the console? may work (not sure, though)

Comment: @Dominik that seems like the opposite of what OP wants.

Comment: Any part of this discussion help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243742/chrome-javascript-debugging-how-to-save-break-points-between-page-refresh-or-b

Comment: @Dominik, `location.reload(true)` is not related to this issue.

Comment: @JamesHill, I have seen it but it is not related.

Comment: sorry, just overlooked it very short. nvm ;)

Comment: Why don't you "bust" it if it changes; aka, use a file timestamp or hash or commit number, as a parameter? :)

Comment: Do you need your breakpoints while the page is reloading, or is it just an inconvenience losing the breakpoints it reloads?

Comment: @Caramiriel OP wrote that it's production code, so I guess changes to the server code are not an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a URL-rewrite Chrome plugin like [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) (not free) or [Redirector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/ocgpenflpmgnfapjedencafcfakcekcd?hl=en) (free) and add redirect rule for your scripts.

Requestly for example lets you specify rules like:

[image: Requestly rule screenshot]

I'm OFC assuming that if you strip the `?bust=xxxx` part from the URL the server will still serve the correct script file. I tested it and it works like a charm in my local test environment - the breakpoints remain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It looks like exactly what I need. I am going to give it a try

Comment: @jannis, Arashoft You can also use the same approach to redirect your URL of production file to somewhere locally hosted JS file - which can be non-minified and non-ofcuscated version of your prod code. This can help you debug even faster. Disclaimer: Requestly Author here!! Good News: Requestly is coming to Firefox soon!! Happy debuggin

Comment: Unfortunately Requestly is not free anymore and I do not want to pay for every simple task in my development. I suggest to use free url redictor extensions such as Redirector to redirect the url and remove the bust. It works perfectly fine in my case.

Comment: It seems in Chrome in the Sources Tab the redirected request is not showing for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `debugger;` within your code. If the developer console is open, execution will break. It works in firebug as well.

Comment: I have to commit and send the JS file to server in order to debug it. It will break the code for current users.

Comment: Debugging in Chrome may just not be what you are looking for then. You can always try other browsers or even external debuggers such as Webstorm. http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/debugging-and-testing.html